# Remove comments from txt file

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code that I need to adjust so that it removes all lines with // while copying. I tried to do:

```
f (prevkar == '/' &&kar!= '/' )
            uitput.put ('/');
```

but it didn't seem to work.

```
output.open ("output.txt",ios::out);
kar = input.get ( );
while ( ! input.eof ( ) )
{
    //this part needs to be adjusted
    output.put (kar);
    kar = input.get ( );
}
```

Comment: When creating a [mcve] to show us, please do it of your actual attempt. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change it to the following: (supposed your input is null-terminated)

```cpp
bool linebreak=false, putknel=false;
while (kar!='\0')
{

    if(linebreak)
    {
        if(kar=='\n')linebreak=false;
    }
    if(kar!='/')
    {
        output.put (kar);
        if(putknel)
        {
            putknel=false;
            output.put('/');
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if(!putknel)putknel=true;
        else 
        {
            putknel=false;
            linebreak=true;
        }
    }
    kar = input.get ( );
}
```

But this may be somewhat tedious.

If you use the **regular expression** it will be much easier.

Just replace all that match `//[^\r\n]*\r\n` to empty strings.